# Is the `\summon` command broken?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Based on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYDetuX3cM8) video. I tried to make this kind of rocket launcher for my mini game.

I Used this command:

```
/execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ /summon Fireball ~ ~ ~ {Motion:[0.0,0.0,0.0],direction:[0.0,0.0­,0.0]}
```

but I got:

```
unable to summon object.
```

I used the 15w51b snapshot. I think I also tested this a while back in 1.8 but i can't remember if it worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### No.

I just did some testing in 1.8.9, as well as the 1.9 snapshots 15w51b and 16w03a. Fireball (and SmallFireball) *require* you to specify the `direction` tag (the `Motion` tag is not needed!), see the invalid "bug" [MC-86011](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-86011). In 1.8.9, a Fireball without `direction` will simply vanish immediately. In the snapshots/1.9, the direction tag is more strict: It needs to exist, and needs to contain exactly 3 doubles. Otherwise, you'll will get a message saying "Unable to summon".

In any case, if a `direction` tag is correctly specified, the object will be summoned.

Now the problem you are having is that there is a strange hidden character in your direction tag, which can be seen when you copy-paste the command into Minecraft (SE doesn't show it at all):

[image: hidden character as seen in Minecraft]

This character causes Minecraft to think the second entry of the tag is a string rather than a double, and Minecraft promptly throws it out. Your `direction` tag now has only 2 entries and is therefore invalid, which causes your problems. You can copy-paste this command instead:

```
/execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ /summon Fireball ~ ~ ~ {direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}
```

<sup>Thanks to @Skylinerw for explaining the technical details.</sup>

Comment: Just to clarify for differences between 1.8/19: `direction` must exist in 1.8 for the fireball to not be deleted instantly when summoned and can contain any data, but in 1.9 it must exist *and* contain 3 Doubles, no more or less. In his original NBT, since the root type of the `direction` was declared as a Double, all the remaining records must be the same type. Because the Soft Hyphen character causes the second record to be a string, it gets thrown out, and thus the list only contains 2 Doubles.

Comment: @Skylinerw Oooh, technical details, very nice. I tried to incorporate your comment into the answer, can you just double-check if it's correct and/or [edit] if not?

Comment: Yep, looks good!